# Testing Redux Saga. Payload is expected, but undefined is recieved

Tags: redux, redux-saga

I'm learning to write tests for sagas. And I have the next saga:

```
export function* searchTemplatesSaga(
  action: ReturnType<typeof searchTemplates>,
): SagaIterator {
  try {
    yield put(startLoading(searchTemplates));

    const { data: templates }: AxiosResponse<Paginated<Template>> = yield call(
      searchTemplatesRequest,
      {},
      action.payload,
    );

    yield put(setTemplates(templates));
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(appError({ error }));
  } finally {
    yield put(stopLoading(searchTemplates));
  }
}
```

And my test looks like this:

```
  it('', () => {
    const saga = searchTemplatesSaga(searchTemplates(mockSearchTemplate));

    expect(saga.next().value).toEqual(put(startLoading(searchTemplates)));

    expect(saga.next().value).toEqual(call(
      searchTemplatesRequest,
      {},
      searchTemplates(mockSearchTemplate).payload,
    ));

    expect(saga.next(mockTempl).value).toEqual(put(setTemplates(mockTempl)));

    ...
  });
```

The problem is that the first call next() and the second call next() pass the test, and the third call next() corresponding to put(setTemplates(mockTempl)) fails.

[image]

Please help me figure out what could be the matter. Why is the accepted payload undefined? I am passing data to the next() call.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to move your mockTempl argument to the earlier saga.next() call where you assert the call effect.

I would highly suggest you move to the run saga pattern of testing sagas.
It is more predictable and you can mock axios using jest.
https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/Testing.html

Comment: I've already tried moving the mockTempl argument to an earlier saga.next() and it did't work.
When I decided to do tests for the sagas, I started by looking at the documentation you shared. Then I chose the library for testing redux-saga-test-plan because from the very beginning I wanted to do an integration test, not a step-by-step test of the saga. But when I started doing integration tests using the test-plan library I got stuck on the same error as in the question. And to figure it out, I started testing the saga step by step.